Issue with using dot character in keynames flutter sharedpreferences fails test case
I am saving a list of names to shared preference in flutter, the scenario is previously the application was saving a list of names under a key "flutter.savedName", but the request has changed to get all the previously saved names under "flutter.savedName" and save under key "models", the following is the code
  Future<void> migratePreviousName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> namelist = prefs.getStringList("flutter.savedName") ?? [];
    if (namelist.isNotEmpty) {
      prefs.remove("flutter.savedName");
      await addNames(namelist);
    }
  }

  Future<void> addNames(List<String> models) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String>? namelist = (await getAllNames() as List<String>?) ?? [];
    namelist.addAll(models);
    prefs.setStringList("models", namelist.toList());
  }

  Future<List<String>> getAllNames() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getStringList("models") ?? [];
  }

and the following is the test case,
   test(
      'Migrate Names',
      () async {
        SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({
          "flutter.savedName": ["Nokia", "Pixel"].toList()
        });
        await handler.migratePreviousName();
        await handler.addNames(["iPhone", "Samsung"]);
        final list = await handler.getAllNames();
        expect(list.length, 4);
      },
    );

The test case is failing , but if I change the key name from "flutter.savedName" to "savedName", the test case passes. Since the key is existing I need to use "flutter.savedName", Understand it is due to the dot in the key name. Is there a solution ?

There's no correlation between the results and key names.
I think you have missed to wait for setting that list:
prefs.setStringList("models", namelist.toList()); 

Fix
await prefs.setStringList("models", namelist.toList());

Wait to get the completed result of that asynchronous operation.
Hope it helps you.

As mentioned in the question it works if the key name is savedName instead of flutter.savedName which is weird.yeah I will try out your suggestion

converting prefs.setStringList("models", namelist.toList()) to async operation didn't pass the test case
